# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: when get file in robot

Tags: robotframework

I'm use keyword Get File of library OperatingSystem for get detail of file I didn't include the complete file name. By omitting the remaining names, use * but it return OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'file name'

Comment: I had a look at Get File documentation and I don't think it allows wildcards. It is available for some keywords like Copy Files and it's documentation shows it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Get File](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20File) does not accept wildcards. You must give it a complete filename.

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving your filename as :

```
C:\Users\user_name\PycharmProjects\RobotFramework\venv\data\test_data_quote.json
```

Try replacing it as :

```
C:\\Users\\user_name\\PycharmProjects\\RobotFramework\\venv\\data\\test_data_quote.json
```

Get File should be able to read it fine.